# The Fourier Coefficient Calculation.

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I want to calculate the Fourier Cofficient for the function defined by:
$$f(\theta) =\frac {(\pi - \theta)^{2}}{4}$$ for $0 \leq\theta \leq 2\pi.$

but the definition for the Fourier Coefficient is from $-\pi$ to $\pi$ for the functions that is integrable on this interval.So, in my function shall I change  the boundaries in the definition of the Fourier Coeffient to be from 0 to $2\pi.$

But I do not think so because if I do this then I found that 
$$\hat{f}(0) = \frac{\pi^{2}}{4}$$ 
But it is answered in the book as:$$\hat{f}(0) = \frac{\pi^{2}}{12}$$

Could anyone give me an advice?

thanks.

Comment: You are right that you only need to change the domain from $[-\pi,\pi]$ to $[0,2\pi].$ It's hard so say what's going wrong cause you haven't shown anything beyond that. The integral to get the constant term in the fourier series is just the average value $ \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi} f(x)dx = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{(x-\pi)^2}{4}dx.$ The result of the integral is the one you report from the book.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen....  In our book, the integral to get the Fourier Coeffients is as u said but $f(x)$ is multiplied by$ e^{-inx}$. and for 0 instead of x, it will give my answer(you can check by substituting in the second integration that you wrote in the previous comment).

Comment: You substitute zero for $n$ not for $x$ to get the zeroth fourier coefficient. (i.e. the constant term.) $x$ is a dummy variable in the integration so setting it equal to zero doesn't make sense.

Comment: your are right ... thanks :)